# Battery Calibration - Battery Percentage Going Down While Off-But-Charging (Pixel 5a)

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, calibration

My phone (Pixel 5a) went from 100% battery to off quite quickly, and it had been doing so. When it died from 100%, I turned it back on. It turned on, showed 0%, and died within a minute. I plugged it in (via USB-C, not wireless).

While off but charging (without interruption), I checked and found it steadily increasing toward 100%. I saw it at 93%, then 97%, but then it went to 96%, 95%, and 93%. Hours later, it's still plugged in but showing 92%.

Is the battery discovering that its maximum charge is much higher than it had been? Or, despite a charging animation on the "off but charging" screen, is the phone discharging?

I'm not sure about the version, but it is the latest standard/stable OS and security version as of today (2023.10.23).

Comment: Try a different charger, different cable and even try wireless charging and compare the device behavior. And my recommendation is to primarily charge the phone in on state (not in the mini charging-OS). If there is no difference in behavior your battery may be bad and needs to be replaced. Note that charging the battery often to 100% or letting it go down next to 0% decreases battery life.